# high disk Wrrite IO on mysqld

Tags: mysql-8.0

I'm facing a rather weird issue with mysqld v8.0.36
there's constantly very high disk write operations(~300MB/s) coming from mysqld.
Although there's a single database hosted on this server(wordpress) which is 5gb in size and it's mostly used for select queries, the disk write ios are pretty high constantly.

```
 835622 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 25.33 % mysqld [ib_log_flush] 
 835624 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s  254.62 M/s  0.00 %  6.81 % mysqld [ib_log_writer] 
 835619 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s   11.32 M/s  0.00 %  6.49 % mysqld [ib_pg_flush-3] 
 835616 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s   10.36 M/s  0.00 %  4.80 % mysqld [ib_pg_flush_co]
 835618 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s   10.39 M/s  0.00 %  3.73 % mysqld [ib_pg_flush-2]
 835617 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    8.61 M/s  0.00 %  3.08 % mysqld [ib_pg_flush-1]
 835615 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  1.91 % mysqld [ib_io_wr-4]   
 835613 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  1.83 % mysqld [ib_io_wr-2]
 835614 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  1.01 % mysqld [ib_io_wr-3]  
 835612 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.80 % mysqld [ib_io_wr-1]   
 835665 be/4 mysql      47.38 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.02 % mysqld [connection]
```

here's /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
disable-log-bin=1
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
performance-schema=1
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_redo_log_capacity=2G
innodb_log_buffer_size=2G
skip-name-resolve=0
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=40000
innodb_file_per_table=1
mysqlx=0
join_buffer_size=4G
log-error-verbosity=1
max_heap_table_size=256M
tmp_table_size=256M
tmpdir=/dev/shm
```

how can i diagnose the issue?

UPDATE: i can see that that mysqld writes at this path:

```
/var/lib/mysql/#innodb_redo
```

UPDATE2: ran show processlist but there are mostly select queries there.

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+-------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id    | User             | Host      | db                 | Command | Time  | State                      | Info                                                                                                 |
+-------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+-------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     5 | event_scheduler  | localhost | NULL               | Daemon  | 10801 | Waiting on empty queue     | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 14859 | root             | localhost | NULL               | Query   |     0 | init                       | show processlist                                                                                     |
| 16086 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live   | Sleep   |     2 |                            | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 16169 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live   | Sleep   |    11 |                            | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 16175 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live   | Query   |     0 | executing                  | SELECT * FROM `ZDz6G_postmeta` LIMIT 1872353, 25000                                                  |
| 16187 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live   | Sleep   |     1 |                            | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 16190 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live   | Sleep   |     0 |                            | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 16195 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live   | Sleep   |     0 |                            | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 16197 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live   | Query   |     0 | waiting for handler commit | INSERT INTO `ZDz6G_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_timeout_ |
| 16199 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | information_schema | Query   |     0 | Opening tables             | SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `ZDz6G_woocommerce_sessions`                                                  |
| 16200 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live   | Query   |     0 | executing                  | SELECT t.term_id, t.name, t.slug, tt.parent FROM ZDz6G_term_taxonomy tt
        INNER JOIN ZDz6G_ter |
+-------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+-------+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
mysql> show processlist;
+-------+------------------+-----------+------------------+---------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Id    | User             | Host      | db               | Command | Time  | State                  | Info                                                |
+-------+------------------+-----------+------------------+---------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|     5 | event_scheduler  | localhost | NULL             | Daemon  | 10796 | Waiting on empty queue | NULL                                                |
| 14859 | root             | localhost | NULL             | Query   |     0 | init                   | show processlist                                    |
| 16086 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live | Sleep   |    16 |                        | NULL                                                |
| 16161 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live | Sleep   |     1 |                        | NULL                                                |
| 16164 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live | Sleep   |     1 |                        | NULL                                                |
| 16166 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live | Sleep   |     1 |                        | NULL                                                |
| 16169 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live | Sleep   |     6 |                        | NULL                                                |
| 16175 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live | Query   |     0 | executing              | SELECT * FROM `ZDz6G_postmeta` LIMIT 1647353, 25000 |
| 16182 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live | Sleep   |     0 |                        | NULL                                                |
| 16183 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live | Sleep   |     0 |                        | NULL                                                |
| 16184 | anagapas_wc_live | localhost | anagapas_wc_live | Sleep   |     0 |                        | NULL                                                |
+-------+------------------+-----------+------------------+---------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
11 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

UPDATE3: maybe its worth to mention that the same database with the same usage on another server doesn't produce the same results.

Comment: what are the processes that run at that time, heavy queries that must use the database, update indert deleting, would cause that. ,maybe enabling general log and see whivh queries run at that time

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! The output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST` might also be helpful!

Comment: @Vérace information added. thanks for your time.

Comment: as   you see in your processlist you lots of processes and alomst all w wating, we stil know nothing about which queries andhow your database looks like

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: This command picked from above, SELECT * FROM `ZDz6G_postmeta` LIMIT 1647353, 25000  asks the system to read through 1,647,353 rows and then select the next 25,000 rows to present to the user.  How will anyone use 25,000 rows of every column in the next week?  Not Likely to be of much help to anyone.  A WHERE column name and selection value would probably be more helpful to a person.  If you could post any of the Additional information requested Mar 12, 2024 about 9:12 we might have some suggestions to reduce response time of your server to complete queries.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to identify which queries are generating the abnormal behavior. A simple way is to turn on the Audit log to collect every query running.

Go to your Mysql client and run:

```
SET global log_output = 'FILE';
SET global general_log_file='/var/log/mysql_general.log';
SET global general_log = 1;
```

Let it collect information for a few minutes, and then turn it off with:

```
SET global general_log = 0;
```

Review the log and see if you can identify what is causing the issue.